# xCode recording in AAC format not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, audio-recording

Here is my code for recording audio in my iOS8 Swift app:

```
var fileName = "/SFRecording-" + String(recordingSequence) + ".caf"
var str =  storageLocation + fileName
var url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(str as String)

audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord, error: nil)
audioSession.setActive(true, error: nil)

var recordSettings = [
    AVFormatIDKey:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4,
    AVSampleRateKey:44100.0,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey:2,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey:12800,
    AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey:16,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue
]
    var error: NSError?

    realRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL:url, settings: recordSettings as [NSObject : AnyObject], error: &error)
```

It works fine but the resultant `CAF` file is useless on windows systems. I wanted to record in a more familiar format like `MP3` but turns out you cannot in iOS due to licensing issues.

Now I want to record in `AAC` format for which I have switched the file extension from `.CAF` to `.AAC` in above code and also switched value in `AVFormatIDKey:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4` to `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC` but those settings fail to record anything. Am I suppose to change some other setting too to make AAC recording work?

Remember my objective is to record in a format which is readily playable on mac/win/browser

Comment: Have you tried saving it with the extension .m4a ?

Comment: @Leonardo Savio Dabus: Doesnt work: `OSStatus error 1685348671.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I had to remove below lines for .AAC format to work:

```
AVSampleRateKey:44100.0,
AVNumberOfChannelsKey:2,
AVEncoderBitRateKey:12800,
AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey:16,
```